# How to search only totally free images in Google?

Tags: google-image-search

I needed an image of a robot for a presentation, and I wanted an image with a free (e.g. creative commons) license. I searched in Google images "robot free", but got mostly royalty-free images (i.e. after you buy the image, you are free to use it).

I remember that once it was possible to search in Google for images with a public-domain or creative-commmons license, but now I cannot find it. Where is it?

Comment: For what it's worth, the Bing image search has the "license" option front-and-center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CC Search](http://search.creativecommons.org) gives access to Google free images, and a few other types too.

Answer (score 6):

Go to "advanced search" (use [this link](http://www.google.com/advanced_search) or use the "Settings" menu) and filter by licence.

[image: Google image licence search]

Comment: Thanks! This worked but was quite complicated: I had to go to the "advanced search" link http://www.google.com/advanced_search , enter the search words, select the license, click "Advanced Search", and then click "Images". For some reason, the "license" settings are not preserved for me between searches.